# how to set the arduino due adc automatic trigger

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-due, adc

How do I trigger automatic conversion on the ADC on the DUE? If this was the uno, I could just do
 `sbi(ADCSRA,ADATE); sbi(ADCSRA,ADSC);`
but for the due, I seem to have to use
`adc_configure_trigger(ADC, ADC_TRIG_SW, 0);` 
Though I am not seeing an auto trigger option, only software/external triggers. Will it just know to start conversion once it sees data coming through?

Comment: Adc has register ADC_MR (adc mode register) and also flag FREERUN...

Comment: so would setting `adc_configure_trigger(ADC, ADC_MR, 1);`  set up automatic trigger?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe. Or maybe `adc_configure_trigger(ADC, ADC_TRIG_SW, ADC_MR_FREERUN_ON);`